# Drupal - Attach files automatically by name to nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i need better file attachement function. Best would be that if you upload files to FTP and have a similar name as the name of the node (containing the same word), so they appear under this node (to not have to add each file separately if you need to have more nodes below). Can you think of a solution? Alternatively, some that will not be as difficult as it always manually add it again.

Dan.

Comment: This is a very, very bad idea...what happens when you've got two nodes with the same title?

Comment: That is exactly what my point. When the node name will be similar, the same files are attached. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This would take a fair bit of coding. Basically you want to implement `hook_cron()` and run a function that loops through every file in your FTP folder. The function will look for names of files that have not already been added to any node and then decide which node to add them to.

Bear in mind there will be a delay once you upload your files until they are attached to the node until the next cron job runs.

This is **not** a good solution and if I could give you any advice it would be not to do it - The reason you upload files through the Drupal interface is so that they are tracked in the `files` table and can be re-used.

Also the way you're proposing leaves massive amounts of ambiguity as to which file will go where. Consider this:

You have two nodes, one about cars and one about motorcycle sidecars. Your code will have to be extremely complex to make the decision of which node to add to if the file you've uploaded is called 'my-favourite-sidecar.jpg'.